# Nvidia graphics card not working

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I just bought a new asus nvidia GeForce gtx1060 for my desk top. I used the "add drivers " menu, clicked nvidia binary, then restarted my computer. When the hard drive boots a black screen with a white blinking margin appears and the computer doesn't continue to the Ubuntu screen. Can anyone help please??

Comment: are you using an Ubuntu driver or nVidia driver? Ubuntu kernels 4.4 and newer require secure boot to be off in order to use third party drivers

Comment: Ok, I have a gigabyte award bios. Do you know where to locate secure boot option?

Comment: Boot settings or maybe security. It varies from machine to machine, and Firmware to Firmware. You just have to look for it.  You are booting 64-bit EFI right?

Comment: How do I attached a picture? Yes

Comment: What is your desktop make and model? Maybe someone here knows what your BIOS screen looks like.

Comment: Gigabyte ga-78lmt-usb3